# Increase or remove content length restrictions in Spring-Boot's embedded Netty

Tags: spring-boot, netty, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm putting a Spring Cloud Gateway in front of some existing microservices. It mostly works, but I have a websocket (SockJS) connection which (apparently) transfers huge amounts of data.

Turns out that Netty apparently has a content length maximum -- when I trip that limit in my SockJS route, I get this error:

```
2018-06-22 16:47:58.740 ERROR 11164 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] r.ipc.netty.channel.ContextHandler       : Error cannot be forwarded to user-facing Mono

io.netty.handler.codec.TooLongFrameException: content length exceeded 65536 bytes.
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageAggregator.handleOversizedMessage(MessageAggregator.java:399) [netty-codec-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageAggregator.invokeHandleOversizedMessage(MessageAggregator.java:383) [netty-codec-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageAggregator.decode(MessageAggregator.java:277) [netty-codec-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:88) [netty-codec-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310) [netty-codec-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:284) [netty-codec-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434) [netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965) [netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163) [netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645) [netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580) [netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497) [netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459) [netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884) [netty-common-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_161]
```

**How do I configure the embedded Netty in spring-boot to not have a content length limit?** I have no control over the length of the message being returned in the response.

The route in the gateway looks like this:

```
- id: check_status_sockjs
  uri: http://foo.example.com:8080
  predicates:
    - Path=/foo/status/**
  filters:
    - RewritePath=/foo/status/(?<segment>.*), /status/$\{segment}
```

The service at the other end that I'm routing the sockJS request to is a Spring-Boot app as well, deployed as a war in a Tomcat 8.5 server. When I interact directly with the backing service, I do not run into any issues with this content length stuff -- it's only when I try to route through the embedded Netty in my gateway app.

I also successfully send and receive smaller messages across this route -- it's only when I hit this apparent length limit does it explode.

My dependencies in the gateway are this:

- spring-cloud-starter-gateway (2.0.0.RELEASE)
- spring-boot-starter-webflux (2.0.2.RELEASE)
- spring-boot-starter-actuator (2.0.2.RELEASE)

Comment: Did you try `-Dhttp.netty.maxInitialLineLength`? See https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/5036, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43813715/io-netty-handler-codec-toolongframeexception-http-content-length-exceeded-20971 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29189713/p-nettyexception-handling-toolongframeexception-play-framework

Comment: I'm not getting an exception about header length.... My exception is due to content length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is now possible using the following boms:

```
dependencyManagement {
  imports {
    mavenBom("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.2.2.RELEASE")
    mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Hoxton.RELEASE") 
  }
}
```

And then in your gateway application config you can set:

```
spring.cloud.gateway.httpclient.websocket.max-frame-payload-length: <bytes_new_limit>
```

I was struggling with this for a while, my spring boot was on '2.1.10.RELEASE'. They fixed it in the new version of webflux that comes with those managed dependencies.

Answer (score 6):

> How do I configure the embedded Netty in spring-boot to not have a content length limit?

It is currently **not possible**.
See [reactor-netty #223](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/223) and [Spring Framework #16228](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16228).

---

**Analysis:**

> Turns out that Netty apparently has a content length maximum

The limitation comes from `reactor-netty`, not directly from `Netty`.

The limit comes from [`reactor. ... .WebsocketInbound`](http://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/snapshot/api/reactor/netty/http/websocket/WebsocketInbound.html), a Java interface which *will aggregate up to 65,536 bytes per frame*.

I could find only one class that implements `WebsocketInbound`: `HttpServerWSOperations`. This class doesn't change the default method `WebsocketInbound.aggregateFrames` so the limit of 65k bytes remains.

`HttpServerWSOperations` is used by the **final** method `HttpServerOperations.withWebsocketSupport` and it is instantiated directly, so you can not change the implementation.

Comment: I was afraid of this. Am I correct in understanding that this is only a restriction with websockets?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Configuration
public class NettyConfiguration implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<NettyReactiveWebServerFactory> {

    @Value("${server.max-initial-line-length:65536}")
    private int maxInitialLingLength;
    @Value("${server.max-http-header-size:65536}")
    private int maxHttpHeaderSize;

    public void customize(NettyReactiveWebServerFactory container) {
        container.addServerCustomizers(
                httpServer -> httpServer.httpRequestDecoder(
                        httpRequestDecoderSpec -> {
                            httpRequestDecoderSpec.maxHeaderSize(maxHttpHeaderSize);
                            httpRequestDecoderSpec.maxInitialLineLength(maxInitialLingLength);
                            return httpRequestDecoderSpec;
                        }
                )
        );
    }
}
```

This worked for me, I've set both maxHeaderSize and maxInitialLineLength paramenter

Comment: As mentioned in the comments, neither of those properties was the problem.  It was `max-frame-payload-length`, which was not exposed at the time. Further it's not necessary to do all of this code: just set the appropriate `spring.cloud.gateway.httpclient.websocket.*` values in your application properties and spring boot will auto-configure netty for you.